# "End of statement" expected, but no syntax or compiler error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make a list of lists, or a 3 by n list. I need them to be lists, because they have to be mutable for my purposes. This process is giving me build errors saying that "End of statement expected" and "Name list1 is not declared". I also tried adding them directly, but this was also giving me a build error. There are no syntax errors or squigly marks to indicate any kind of syntax error. It's simply saying it did not build with one error and showing this in the build list.

Here is my current code:

```
    Dim listoflists As New ArrayList

    Dim list1 As ArrayList = New ArrayList From {Split(txt1.Text, ",")}

    Dim list2 As ArrayList = New ArrayList From {Split(txt2.Text, ",")}

    Dim list3 As ArrayList = New ArrayList From {Split(txt3.Text, ",")}

    listoflists.Add(list1)
    listoflists.Add(list2)
    listoflists.Add(list3)
```

Previously it was:

```
    Dim listoflists As New ArrayList()

    listoflists.Add(New ArrayList From {Split(txt1.Text, ",")})

    listoflists.Add(New ArrayList From {Split(txt2.Text, ",")})

    listsoflists.Add(New ArrayList From {Split(txt3.Text, ",")})
```

Which also returned build errors but no syntax errors. I liked the simplicity of it better.

Does anyone know why the compiler might not like this configuration and what I can do to make my code work? Thank you!

Edit:

My original code returned the errors "Comma, ')' or a valid expression continuation expected," and "Too many arguments or "Public Overridable Function Add(Value as Object) as Integer", and then "end of statement expected."

Comment: That code, by itself,  doesn't produce the error in question. Please add the whole method in which this code is present

Comment: @Steve weird, when I had an array of arrays, this whole method worked just fine. Do you think it could be some sort of spillover from somewhere else, and this is where the error is being thrown?

Comment: @Steve removing the rest of the module produces the same error. Unfortunately I cannot post the whole code here, but It seems to be related to these lines only as the other lines worked independent of this, but not vice versa.

Comment: If I take your lines and try to run them on LinqPAD  there is no error of the kind you specified. Yes I think that something else is at play here.. Just to test it, try to comment out the Whole method and check if the error is still there

Comment: @Steve I think it could be something with the visual studio interpreter, it's been acting very strangely over this entire project, throwing weird errors, then when I rearrange the code or delete an empty line it will tell me there is no longer an error

Comment: @Steve Is there another mutable datatype that you'd suggest that I can use just to get around this error?

Comment: @Steve I downloaded and installed LINQPad and it's throwing the exact same error.

Comment: Using just the lines shown above? (Of course replacing the textboxes with string constants) - And what is the type of _stbs_ ?

Comment: @steve that should be more clear. I wound up making each list as a new array list. Then I took the split and made it it's own array variable. Then I took the elements of each array and put them in the lists, then put the lists in the list of lists. I was hoping to do it in fewer lines of code, but for whatever reason, it doesn't seem to like {Split...} as a new arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be useful

```
    Dim txtBox1Sim As String = "1.jpg,10.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg"

    Dim listoflists As New List(Of List(Of String))

    'repeat next two lines for each textbox changing what is split
    listoflists.Add(New List(Of String))
    listoflists(listoflists.Count - 1).AddRange(txtBox1Sim.Split(New Char() {","c}))
```